# Scan all HTML for an element class then run javascript on that class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do this process:

1. Find all classes that begin with "i18n_"
2. Capture that class name, then set that class' .html value to a variable with the same name as the class.

Basically I have a list that gets grabbed off the server with all the strings, beginning with i18n_. For example i18n_t23 = "Back" or something. I want to take the `<span class="i18n_t23"></span>` and set it's value to the variable i18n_t23.

At the moment I have a massive list of hand-coded $("span.i18n_t189").html(i18n_t189); and it's getting tiring to have to check if they're all there. There must be a way to just have it do this automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a code example of how you are defining your variables?

Comment: $.each(content.nodes,function(index,obj){
eval("i18n_t" + obj.node.tid + "='" + obj.node.name_i18n + "';");
});

I know that eval is definitely not the best choice here but I really just need to get this out the door as soon as possible. Each i18n_t## is referencing a drupal taxonomy. What I would like to do it just set a span with the class of that taxonomy ID and have it do magic and make those values appear. The issue is multilanguage. By using drupal's taxonomies system I can just define the translation right on the site and have json pull the right one down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend you to slightly change your setup and thus simplify javascript code you've got:

```
<div data-i18="a">a</div>

<div data-i18="b">b</div>

var i18 = { a: 'a2', b: 'b2' }

$('div[data-i18]').each(function(ind, el) {
    var key = $(el).data('i18')
    $(el).html(i18[key])        
});​

// or in case of global variables 

$('div[data-i18]').each(function(ind, el) {
    var key = $(el).data('i18')
    $(el).html(window[key])        
});​
```

So instead of class `i18_something` you are setting up custom data attribute data-i18 and put value here.

Comment: I had to alter it slightly but it makes more sense it seems to use the data-i18 element instead of using class probably incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: LOL I think if we knew you had the ability to modify the HTML code, we would have all recommended something like this. You could do something even simpler by just adding one more class to the current spans and then just searching for that class name and iterating through them.

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
$('span[class^=i18n_]').text(
    function(){
        return this.className;
    });
```

It's worth noting that this sets the *text* of the element to the class-name of the element; a `span` doesn't have a `value` attribute, and setting its `html()` is unnecessary (though in this case it has almost the same result).

Incidentally, depending on what you need this for you could emulate this with simple CSS (in supporting 'modern' browsers):

```
span[class=^=i18n_]::before {
    content: attr(class);
}
```

A means to deal with multiple classes:

```
$('span[class]').filter(
    function(i, e) {
        var el = $(e),
            classes = el.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++) {
            var assessed = classes[i].indexOf('i18n_');
            if (assessed === 0) {
                el.data('classMatch',classes[i]);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }).text(function(){ return $(this).data('classMatch'); });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KVfFS/).

And an approach to handle a lookup (using the returned class-name to retrieve an assigned value from an object:

```
var lookup = {
    'i18n_something' : 'Something for the "something" suffixed class.',
    'i18n_somethingElse' : 'Something for the "somethingElse" version.',
    'i18n_AndSomethingElse' : 'And...well, you know the drill.'
};

$('span[class]').filter(
    function(i, e) {
        var el = $(e),
            classes = el.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++) {
            var assessed = classes[i].indexOf('i18n_');
            if (assessed === 0) {
                el.data('classMatch',classes[i]);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }).text(function(){ return lookup[$(this).data('classMatch')]; });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KVfFS/1/).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but the function may want to return the result of using the class as a lookup key.  Also, this won't work with something like `<span class="something something i18n_xyz">`

Comment: @Pointy: yeah; I was working under the (ridiculously naive) assumption of one class per element. Looking at a simple way of handling the multiple-classes =) As for the lookup, yes. I didn't realise there were no quotes in the `html()` method in the question. Sigh.

Comment: Regular expression would be better for performance, but probably nothing noticeable.

Comment: @Lawrence: I must confess it's been quite some time since I last benchmarked regular expressions against array/string methods. But I recall that they (certainly) used to be slower/more expensive? But you're right, if only in that I need to re-evaluate that (long-held) assumption (by which I'm not saying you're wrong, it's just that I honestly don't know).

Comment: I can't think of a time when Regular Expression were ever more expensive / slower on any platform. The entire reason for their existence is to avoid the extensive amount of additional operations and evaluations it takes to do the same thing (compare your example with mine below).

Answer (score 1):

You try it.
`$("*[class*='i18n_']).attr("class")` or when element only one class name so `$("*[class^='i18n_']).attr("class")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
    var _regClassMatch = /i18n_t([0-9]+)/;
    jQuery.each(jQuery('span'), function () {
        var _oCurrSpan = jQuery(this);
        var _sCurrClass = _oCurrSpan.attr('class');

        var _mClassMatch = _sCurrClass.match(_regClassMatch);
        if (_mClassMatch) {
            alert(_mClassMatch[1]);
        }
    });
```

_mClassMatch[1] is your number value, and the _oCurrSpan object is your current span. Just run it on document.ready.